# asp.net itextsharp convert the file format files to PDF

Tags: pdf, itext, arabic

When I tried to use the code to convert the file format files to PDF using itextsharp. The problem appears when converting texts written in **Arabic**. The result came without the written text in Arabic.
I hope you to help me overcome the problems.

Thank you very much

Comment: check this question that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080741/convert-arabicunicode-content-html-or-xml-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary of the process:

- Wrap `Paragraph` objects in one of the two iText [**IElement**](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Element.html) classes that support Arabic text: [**PdfPCell**](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html) and [**ColumnText**](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html).
- Use a font that has Arabic glyphs.
- Set the text run direction and alignment.

Something like this:

```
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, STREAM);
  document.Open();
  string arabicText = @"
iText ® هي المكتبة التي تسمح لك لخلق والتلاعب وثائق PDF. فإنه يتيح للمطورين تتطلع الى تعزيز شبكة الإنترنت وغيرها من التطبيقات مع دينامية الجيل ثيقة PDF و / أو تلاعب.      
  ";
  PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
  table.WidthPercentage = 100;
  PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
  cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
  cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
  Font font = new Font(BaseFont.CreateFont(
    "c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf",
    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED
  ));
  Paragraph p = new Paragraph(arabicText, font);
  p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  cell.AddElement(p);
  table.AddCell(cell);
  document.Add(table);
}
```

Sorry if the example text above is poor, incorrect, or both. I had to use Google translate, since my native language is English.

Comment: i try this code but i use asp.net depend on vb.net... plz send me this code on vb.net   OR you can send this code in Full Page to i can to use it. many thaks 4 you

Comment: You can [convert the code from C# to VB yourself](http://converter.telerik.com/).